# The longest paragraph competition

Tags: word, open-ended

You must write a paragraph using valid English words (either British or American, but not both in the same answer) and proper grammar. No proper nouns or colloquial/slang words allowed. Quotation marks not allowed. Numbers and punctuation (including necessary and unnecessary ones) are not a problem, they won't be counted in the score.

The sentences need not make sense with respect to each other. For example, `The lion ate the deer. The house is on fire. The ghost fell asleep. It is he who filed the papers last night.` However you cannot make logically impossible or incomprehensible statements like `My kid ate the washing machine. The lion jumped over the moon. The taxi crossed the century.` (I know there is no fine line between what is and what isn't logically comprehensible, so I'll leave it to the users to decide with their up/down votes on the more ambiguous answers.)

The paragraph must include the letter `a` atleast once, `b` atleast twice, `c` atleast thrice and so on. Yes, that means it should have `x` atleast 24 times, `y` atleast 25 times and `z` atleast 26 times.

**Winning:** The post with the lowest number of characters (a-z only) wins. If two posts have the same score, then the older one wins.

**Reward:** I will give a 200 rep bounty for the highest scoring post on 5 Jan 2016.

Comment: Dear OP if you are gonna count the number of letters in the answer, then you are the most wonderful person i could have ever met..:p However there are other ways too to count.

Comment: @manshu ???????????????

Comment: maybe MS word or you can even make an HTML to run in chrome (or may be any other web browser). Put the answer in the HTML and use Ctrl + F to count easily every single letter.

Comment: However the question doesn't seem like a puzzle to me. Its more like a challenge.

Comment: @manshu It is a challenge. And I have no idea what you mean by using Ctrl+F on Chrome. I think you have misunderstood my Q.

Comment: No. I haven't and i am not even trying to answer the question. I am trying to advise you to how to count the number of letters in the answer coz it must be time consuming. I am sure you have your own way to find the number of letters

Comment: "Logically impossible or incomprehensible" is vague. What if the washing machine was from a dollhouse, or one of those dis-assemble-able eraser toys? You can come up with a lot of explanations with varying 'reasonableness', and there's no clear line.

Comment: Besides the vagueness indicated by Deusovi, i'm having trouble seeing why this is getting so many downvotes.. It seems like a fun challenge that requires a lot of puzzling..

Comment: @DrunkWolf It's not really a puzzle... most solutions will just be slightly modified forms of previous ones. Plus, it involves a lot of writing and the scoring criterion makes no sense (you can improve scores by taking out paragraphs).

Comment: So whichever paragraph you have that's best should just be replicated 5 times, perhaps mixing a few nouns around so that it's different enough and yet still comprehensible?

Comment: @DrXorile I did not think of that. I've edited the Q so that asks for only one para.

Comment: @Deusovi Even I could not determine an accurate way of calling a statement logically acceptable. Is it okay if I leave that to the users' discretion? (Obviously valid answers will get up-voted, ambiguous answers may acquire some down-votes too)

Comment: @ghosts At this point, it doesn't seem like a puzzle - it's way too subjective. Plus, even making an answer is very tedious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dr Seuss, eat your heart out!

> Why try fix a dozen very quick, quiet fox zoo boxes? We've zero prize mix boxes. Why try fix very quick, quiet, zero-size fox zoo boxes? We've mixed jump sizes. Why try fix very quick fox zoos. Jump! We've size zero mixes. Why living pigs try to jump? We've mixed very quick, size-zero zoos! Why we've mixed a dozen, quick prize zoos? Why tax prize trunk zoos? Tax two prize zoos! Two sixes equals twelve. Six & six equals a dozen. Queen Jim swung liquid quite quietly. Queen Jim swung quite quickly. Texas town zoo sky view gave us sun & vast joy. Tax my vast, square, box trunk, my next vowel. Next vowel? You put us up. Sky jet put frozen breeze up. Citizen, now go worry. July: I've given Jack, Joe, John & Joy a job supplying pus. Have, wave, jar, & pull are verbs.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out another flaw in the Q. I'll edit to disallow this.

Comment: Edited. I feel like Dr Seuss.

Comment: +15 The Q is closed, so I've accepted your answer just to give you some rep.